# using awk to grab random lines and append to a new column?

Tags: random, awk

So I have a document "1", which is one column. I have 3 files with one column each and I want to append a randomly selected line from each of those columns onto the document 1's line.

So like

```
awk 'NR==10' moves.txt 'NR==1' propp_tasks.txt
```

prints out

```
10.Qg3 Bb4+
   First function of the donor
```

when I want it to be:

```
10 Qg3 Bb4+    First function of the donor
```

Is there a good way to do this with awk? I had been trying to set up a bash script with a for loop but I didn't know how to cycle the indices so on line n of document 1, columns 2,3 and 4 would be appended on there. I feel like this should be really, really simple...

Comment: How long are your files? If they fit in memory it is a piece of cake, if not, performance could be an issue.

Comment: Would you double-check your awk line? I'm getting an error `awk: can't open file NR==1`.

Comment: They're not very long at all, easily fit in memory. I just don't know the awk syntax to append onto a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste 1 <(cat 2 3 4 | sort -R)
```

If the length of the first file and the length of the combination of the other 3 files are different, then some more work is required.